# Remove and add data in large csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I want to edit the following csv file. This is the format I get the input, it is actually from data from the Google Finance API which give stock quotes to a certain stock, in this case its Adidas.
My Service crawls this API day and night and stores it in a csv file.
This is how the file looks:

```
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'9:57AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.36');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 9:57AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.52');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.36')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'9:57AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.36');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 9:57AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.52');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.36')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.29');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:11AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.35');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:11AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.53');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.35')
(u'c', u'-1.01');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:32AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.63');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:32AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.19');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.63')
(u'c', u'-1.01');(u'ccol', u'chr');(u'e', u'FRA');(u'ltt', u'10:32AM GMT+2');(u'l', u'83.63');(u's', u'0');(u'lt', u'Aug 23, 10:32AM GMT+2');(u't', u'ADS');(u'cp', u'-1.19');(u'id', u'7901819');(u'l_cur', u'\u20ac83.63')
```

Now I want to edit each data line in this format (this is the data from line 23 and 24):

```
10:31;2013-08-23;83.35;ADS
10:32;2013-08-23;83.35;ADS
```

**First part the time**:

I want it to increase the time, because every line is one minute. As you can see the line 23 and 24 in the original data have the same than the lines before (10:11AM), that is because the stock price did not changed. But in real they are 10:31AM and 10:32AM. Sometimes the time does not fit exactly (one minute is missing until the new course is given) but that is not that important.
Also I want the time format to be 24h so that it converts me AM and PM to the 24h
 style

**Second part the date**:
I want that it puts me the data in the above format, so that it adds an 2013 (like hardcoded in this case) and that it converts the month "Aug" into an 08. I have several months for this year.

**Third and forth part**:
Just get the data in the given format

The data is 24 hours so one day contains 1440 lines.
I also do only want the data from 08:00 till 20:00.

All the other data should be removed, so that I get the desired format.

For any ideas I would be very pleased.

Comment: Do you have any code so far? What have you tried, and what hasn't worked?

Comment: Have you looked at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module or the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library?  Either might come in handy, and `pandas` in particular has many useful tools for dealing with time series data.

Comment: The panda library looks really fine for the work I have to do afterwards. But it will not help me bringing the data in the desired format at first.

Answer (score 0):

use `;` as a delimiter to differentiate between different parentheses

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import csv, sys, re, time

stock_file = open(sys.argv[1])
parsed = csv.reader(stock_file, delimiter=';')
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout) #change sys.stdout to you preferred file name

info_list = []

for item in parsed:
    d = re.search('\w+.\d+', item[6])
    date = d.group(0)

    t = re.search('\d+.\d+\w+', item[6])
    time_12h = t.group(0)
    time_24h = time.strftime('%H:%M',time.strptime(time_12h, '%I:%M%p'))

    a = re.search('\d+.\d+', item[4])
    amount = a.group(0)

    c = re.search('[A-Z]+', item[7])
    currency = c.group(0)

   info_list.append((date,time,amount,currency))

for a,b,c,d in info_list:
    writer.writerow([a,b,c,d])
```

Here is sample output from the data you provided above

Aug 23,09:57,83.36,ADS
Aug 23,09:57,83.36,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:11,83.35,ADS
Aug 23,10:32,83.63,ADS
Aug 23,10:32,83.63,ADS

Comment: each `Aug 23,9:57AM,83.36,ADS` takes an individual row, not sure how to display it correctly. If anyone knows please edit above output. Cheers

Comment: It is pretty good. As you said, what is missing is that it adds one minute for every new line.

Comment: @Max: sorry I have  miss understood the question. Do you want an increment by one minute for every new line in the loop? How would you like sample output to look, please provide an example?